# subsetting yearmon objects

Tags: r, datetime, subset, zoo

I have monthly data

```
library(zoo); library(data.table)
dat <- data.table(month=as.yearmon(paste0("2019-0",1:9)))
> dat
      month
1: Jan 2019
2: Feb 2019
3: Mrz 2019
4: Apr 2019
5: Mai 2019
6: Jun 2019
7: Jul 2019
8: Aug 2019
9: Sep 2019
```

and I would like to subset it to months after, say, May 2019. Whereas

```
dat[month=="Jun 2019"]
```

works,

```
> dat[month > "May 2019"]
Empty data.table (0 rows and 1 cols): month
> dat[month%in%c("Jun 2019","Jul 2019")]
Empty data.table (0 rows and 1 cols): month
```

do not. Is there a trick?

Comment: What is `,,`?...

Comment: Ah, sorry. Using the iOS app and it’s encoding the quotes differently I guess. Tried to fix it and hope this works.

Comment: How can a value be bigger than a string? You need to convert to proper datetime first and then use `format` to extract a numeric for the month, and then compare

Comment: @Sotos, Those are `yearmon` values and they can be compared.  The string will automatically be converted appropriately to `yearmon` class.  Look at  `zoo:::Ops.yearmon`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck ok. I was not aware it worked like that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it does work.  Fixing the double quotes we have:

```
library(data.table)
library(zoo)

dat <- data.table(month=as.yearmon(paste0("2019-0",1:9), "%Y-%m"))

dat[month > "May 2019"]
##       month
## 1: Jun 2019
## 2: Jul 2019
## 3: Aug 2019
## 4: Sep 2019
```

### Language

The comparison will use the language currently in effect.  For example, if we set the current session to French:

```
Sys.setlocale(locale = "French")
dat[ month > "mai 2019" ]
##         month
## 1:  juin 2019
## 2: juil. 2019
## 3:  août 2019
## 4: sept. 2019
```

We can also do it in a language independent way by using month numbers rather than names:

```
dat[ month > "2019-05" ]
##       month
## 1: Jun 2019
## 2: Jul 2019
## 3: Aug 2019
## 4: Sep 2019
```

### Note

It would be good enough to do this to create the example:

```
dat <- data.table(month = as.yearmon(paste0("2019-", 1:9)))
```

Comment: I saw just now that it appears to be a language issue. Although I set `Sys.setenv(LANG = "en")`, it keeps naming months in German. Can this be changed?

Comment: I added `dat[month%in%c("Jun 2019","Jul 2019")]` to the OP as another command I had tried. As far as I can see, this really does not work. Can you comment on this, too?

Comment: Have added a Language section to the answer.

Comment: Unfortunately `match` does not use `Ops` so if you want to use match you will to ensure that both sides are of the same class. `dat$month %in% as.yearmon(c("Jun 2019","Jul 2019"))`

Comment: Excellent, both answers are very helpful. Thanks.